# Retrieve bulk data from YAML using Python

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a yaml file of the form below:

```
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 1
  number of solutions displayed: 1
- Gap: None
  Status: optimal
  Message: bonmin\x3a Optimal
  Objective:
    objective:
      Value: 0.010981105395
  Variable:
    battery_E[b1,1,1]:
      Value: 0.25
    battery_E[b1,1,2]:
      Value: 0.259912707017
    battery_E[b1,2,1]:
      Value: 0.120758408109
    battery_E[b2,1,1]:
      Value: 0.0899999972181
    battery_E[b2,2,3]:
      Value: 0.198967393893
    windfarm_L[w1,2,3]:
      Value: 1
    windfarm_L[w1,3,1]:
      Value: 1
    windfarm_L[w1,3,2]:
      Value: 1
```

Using Python27, I would like to import all battery_E values from this YAML file. I know I can iterate over the keys of battery_E dictionary to retrieve them one by one (I am already doing it using PyYAML) but I would like to avoid iterating and do it in one go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible "in one go" - there will still be some kind of iteration either way, and that's completely OK.

However, if the memory is a concern, you can load *only* values of the keys of interest during YAML loading:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import yaml

KEY = 'battery_E'


class Loader(yaml.SafeLoader):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        super(Loader, self).__init__(stream)
        self.values = []

    def compose_mapping_node(self, anchor):
        start_event = self.get_event()
        tag = start_event.tag
        if tag is None or tag == '!':
            tag = self.resolve(yaml.MappingNode, None, start_event.implicit)
        node = yaml.MappingNode(tag, [],
                                start_event.start_mark, None,
                                flow_style=start_event.flow_style)
        if anchor is not None:
            self.anchors[anchor] = node
        while not self.check_event(yaml.MappingEndEvent):
            item_key = self.compose_node(node, None)
            item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
            if (isinstance(item_key, yaml.ScalarNode)
                    and item_key.value.startswith(KEY)
                    and item_key.value[len(KEY)] == '['):
                self.values.append(self.construct_object(item_value, deep=True))
            else:
                node.value.append((item_key, item_value))
        end_event = self.get_event()
        node.end_mark = end_event.end_mark
        return node


with open('test.yaml') as f:
    loader = Loader(f)
    try:
        loader.get_single_data()
    finally:
        loader.dispose()

    print(loader.values)
```

Note however, that this code does not assume anything about the position of `battery_E` keys in the tree inside the YAML file - it will just load all of their values.

Comment: Neatly done, but you should point out that this is as unsafe as using `yaml.load()`. I see however no reason not to subclass `yaml.SafeLoader` instead of `yaml.Loader` to circumvent that problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your time and expertise. You solution seems very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to retrieve each entry using PyYAML, you can load the data once, and then use Pythons to select the key-value pairs with the following two lines:

```
data = yaml.safe_load(open('input.yaml'))
kv = {k:v['Value']  for k, v in data['Solution'][1]['Variable'].items() if k.startswith('battery_E')}
```

after that `kv` contains:

```
{'battery_E[b2,2,3]': 0.198967393893, 'battery_E[b1,1,1]': 0.25, 'battery_E[b1,1,2]': 0.259912707017, 'battery_E[b2,1,1]': 0.0899999972181, 'battery_E[b1,2,1]': 0.120758408109}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Anthon. Yes you are right, if data is loaded all at once then why not just iterating. However, I was looking for something similar to the way that I retrieved data from a SQL DB, but I guess that's not possible.

Comment: @Mosy No that is not possible with PyYAML. I hope you realize that with an SQL database the database software iterates all of the table entries to the matches the criteria that you specified (unless of course these are specically indexed in some way).